# Steps to take when deploying a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I've wrapped up version 1 of my desktop application and it's ready for deployment.

Just to test things out, I grabbed the contents of the /debug folder and copies that into a folder of the target machine and the application works.

I'm sure this is not the correct way to do this.

I've created a Visual Studio Installer project and created that as well. My question is, do I have to set something similar to ASP.Net's debug=false, when deploying an application?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several deployment options of .NET applications. Your approach is often called "xcopy deployment" and is a simple copy of all included files.

Typically you don't copy the content from the debug folder. Instead you change the "Solutions Configuration" combo in Visual Studio from debug to release, compile the application and copy the files from the "Release" folder instead.

When creating a release build of your application the compiler applies more optimizations to the code to create a more efficient executable.

There are other methods of deployment. Here are some that creates different kinds of installers

- ClickOnce (Right click on your project in solution explorer and choose "Publish")
- Installer project (creates an MSI installer)
- [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (creates MSI installers too, is more cumbersome than an installer project, but more flexible
- etc.

The benefit of creating an installer is that it is usually simpler for an end user to run an installer than it is to copy a loose bunch of files. An installer can automatically create an icon on the start menu, make sure the correct version of .NET framework is installed etc.

If you only want to run your application on one or at most a few computers it is probably not worth the extra work of creating an installer.

Answer (score 4):

I would do the following when creating a "release candidate" of your app:

- Create a branch or tag in your source control repository identifying a particular build as the source of the release candidate. A branch is nice because it allows you to make changes necessary to release the source that you don't want in your dev environment.
- Set up the Release build configuration of your app. Among other things, yes, this does ensure the DEBUG compile constant is not set, so anything that is conditionally compiled based on that constant will not be. Default behavior is also to optimize the code (faster runtime, not debuggable) and to not generate PDBs.
- Build the installer. Ideally, the output of the installer should go somewhere else than the main output of the primary project.
- Run the installer (doing so from its build location is fine). It should execute with no errors, and produce what you expect.
- "Smoke test" the application as installed. Basically, run through some basic operations that do not modify the data layer it works against, that will verify there are no major problems with the app possibly caused by a missing DLL or incorrect connection strings/app settings.
- Copy the installer to a thumb drive of sufficient size, and try the same installation and smoke test on a "virgin" computer that does not have VS installed. Ideally, it should mimic the environment of the target machines as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you shouldn't be deploying the Debug assmeblies. You should build in Release mode. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

I've never used the Installer projects, but I tend to stay more towards web and console stuff. Hopefully someone else will have a more detailed post :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Setup and Deployment project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). This way your application will make sure user's have required libraries. It will also download the required .net version if it is not installed.

And always release the "release" version and not the debug version. Copy/Paste from debug folder will not work in call the cases and its not the right way to release an application.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want someone reverse engineering your code, you might want to use Dotfuscate.