# C# winforms application what's next?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-6

So a friend has asked to develop a desktop application in order to ease his work, it's not too big or crazy just some simple crud operation and some search tasks here & there.

I have finished the application now it's time to deliver it.

I have never delivered an app before and never really found myself in that situation since I am a total beginner with absolutely no real world experience so am super new to this, but I can handle and deliver what I am asked to do.

Some information about the application:

- Developped using C# ( winforms ) on top of .Net ( 4.5 )
- SQL Server 2014
- Entity Framework 6.

So how do I deliver this to his workstation, I have read in the last days these a lot ( release , deploy , publish ) kinda got confused because the explanations were too vague plus the english that was used was a little bit difficult for me since it's not my native language.

Please let me know what should I be aware of, and I would love to see like step by step how to do this, and how professionals do it.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day to each and every one of you.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio did you use?

Comment: @JimHewitt Visual Studio 2015

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

Comment: if you don't need installer you can go to bin/debug folder in your project folder and copy all files from there to your friends pc. After that just run your_project_name.exe and you should be fine:)

Comment: @RomanSidorov does this solution is the same this " installer " process ??

Comment: @RedaRACHID pretty much the same, except in installer you can also include sql database and .net framework components, which will be required for your app. If you go for my option, don't forget to install them manually.

Comment: @Reda You may want to check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070081/steps-to-take-when-deploying-a-windows-forms-application.  It's' a little old but should  still be valid.

Comment: @RomanSidorov ok thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @JimHewitt thank you sir your answer was very insightfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my solution (Windows Form application with a SQL Server Database using EntityFramework), I used ClickOnce to publish it.

[How to: Publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)

You have to be sure that all the assembly you use in your project (.dll) are installed on the computer like those containing entity framework. You can easily find them on Microsoft website.

If your database is a local database, you have to install sql server express LocalDB on the computer.

And then, you only have to double click on the generated file from clickOnce and it will launch an installer wizard. If it fail, it shows you the error in detail and you can easily fix it.

Finally, you have to validate the connection string in your configuration file to be sure that it is pointing to your database.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what ClickOnce is for. It's not a heavy duty installer, but perfect for a one-off lightweight app.